# No frameworks section in jsfiddle

Tags: frameworks, jsfiddle

[No extension and frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwzjv.jpg)

Hello!
I opened https://jsfiddle.net/ in my Firefox browser and expected to see "Frameworks&Extensions" section there. Howevere, it was not there. Can someone please advice what should I do in order to add the section? Please follow the image link for more details. I suppose that I should add some add on to my browser but can't guess what should it be. It is also not working in Chrome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As outlined in a recent post [on medium](https://medium.com/jsfiddle-updates/the-lifting-cb3c9f216c2f#.2ms9s7deg) the ability to add frameworks and extensions has moved into the Javascript pane within JsFiddle.

Within a fiddle, click on the 'Javascript' 'button' at the top right of the Javascript pane to reveal the new menu.